# Знак «Просветитель»

Tags: поддержка, знаки

Нормы для многих значков считаю завышенными, но этот...

[Описание гласит](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/92/illuminator):

> Отредактировать 500 вопросов и ответить на них (оба действия в течение 12 часов, рейтинг за ответы > 0).

500 редактирований + 500 ответов = 1000 действий за 60 * 12 = 720 минут. Выходит, программист, не встающий ни на минуту из-за компьютера, на одно действие должен потратить 0.72 мин * 6/10 = 43,2 сек. Как это возможно? Или чего-то недопонял?

Comment: Правка и ответ в течение 12 часов. А не 500 правок и 500 ответов.

Comment: @Nofate, спасибо, понятно. Поправить бы описание во избежание разночтений.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно так переформулировать.

> Отредактировать вопрос и ответить на него (оба действия должны быть в интервале 12 часов, рейтинг ответа > 0), повторить `%number%` раз.

Answer (score 2):

> Внести правку в вопрос и опубликовать на него же ответ (в пределах 12 часов) с положительным рейтингом `%number%` раз.

Comment: Можно и в обратном порядке. )

Comment: @NickVolynkin можно, и в пояснении нет слов "затем", "после" и подобных :)

Comment: да, действительно)

Answer (score 1):

Ещё вариант:

> Отредактировать и ответить на `%number%` различных вопросов (оба действия должны быть в интервале 12 часов, рейтинг ответа > 0).

Answer (score 1):

Мой вариант:

> Предложить правку и ответ (оба действия должны быть в интервале 12 часов, рейтинг ответа > 0) для %number% вопросов.

Comment: Тонкость в том, что правка должна быть принята.